# Spring MVC simple access control from interceptor: how to display error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In a Spring 4.2 webapp, I have a `rights` object in the session from which I can query whether the logged in user has access to a specific page. I can check the access rights from a controller and redirect to another page with a message. The problem is I have to repeat this for every request method in every controller.

I can move almost all the code to an interceptor but I have no access to `RedirectAttributes` from there,  so I don't know how I could add the error message. Is there a way?

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("rights")
@RequestMapping("/f")
public class FController {
   ...
    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(@PathVariable("id") int id,
        @ModelAttribute("rights") UserRights rights,
        RedirectAttributes redA, ModelMap model) throws SQLException {
        if (!rights.canAccess("/f/edit")) {
            redA.addFlashAttribute("errormessage", messages.getMessage("error.noright", null, Locale.getDefault()));
            return "redirect:/f/list";
        }
        ... // set up model
        return "fEdit";
    }
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! It is not as well integrated as what you get in controller methods, but you can get access to the output flash map in an interceptor. You can find references for that in the chapter on [Using flash attributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes) in Spring Framework ReferenceManual. And thanks to the [`ModelAndViewDefiningException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndViewDefiningException.html), you can still ask Spring to do the redirect and process the output flash map

You could just put something like this in an interceptor:

```
    if (!rights.canAccess("/f/edit")) {
        // get access to the output flash map
        FlashMap redA = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(HttpServletRequest request);
        // add the redirect attributes
        redA.put("errormessage", messages.getMessage("error.noright", null, Locale.getDefault()));
        // prepare the redirection
        ModelAndView redirMav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/f/list");
        // ask the spring machinery to process the redirection
        throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(redirMav);
    }
```